# How to make dynamic input parameters based on another query response in an Integromat app?

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

I am implementing an API that has an endpoint which returns a list of custom fields for objects such as company, lead, etc.
When creating a lead, the user should be able to enter custom fields alongside the hardcoded ones.
How can this be done dynamically in the Mappable parameters of a module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an RPC (procedure for getting of dynamic input fields via API) and combine it with static parameters like in the example below:

Mappable parameters:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "uinteger",
        "label": "Static parameter"
    },
    "rpc://getDynamicFields"
]
```

Ref: https://docs.integromat.com/apps/structure-blocks/expect#rpc

How to create RPC you can find here: https://docs.integromat.com/apps/app-structure/rpcs#fields-rpc

Comment: How can this work, this is not even valid JSON

Comment: Does this also work for select input options?